# Set diffrent value for Sharepoint custom property of same web part in multiple diffrent pages

Tags: visual-web-part

I have visual web part and i am attempting to set custom property unique value on each pages. For example i have two aspx pages. Deal.aspx and Fund.aspx. Both page is having same web part used. When i set the value custom property in web part of Deal.aspx the same value gets reflect in Fund.aspx page web part as well. I read about PersonalizationScope but it did not help for my scenario. Below is  the custom property i have created.

```
    public static string ListName;
    [Category("Extended Settings"),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User),
    WebBrowsable(true),
    WebDisplayName("Enter List Name"),
    WebDescription("Please Enter a List Name")]

    public string _ListName
    {
        get { return ListName; }
        set
        {
            // Sample Validation
            Regex oRegEx = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+");
            if (!oRegEx.IsMatch(value))
                throw new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.
                    WebPartPageUserException(
                    "Please enter alphabeth characters only");
            ListName = value;
        }
    }
```

I will highly appreciate the help. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the static keyword on ListName field